# Why is VS Code using the tab key to move focus from the integrated terminal instead of sending the keypress to the shell?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to use VS Code to open WSL workspace and terminal, but I found it will move my focus of VS Code when I type some command and try to use tab to complete my command.

For now only thing I can do is clicking the button in the status bar, which will still be the same after I click in other active window, or press Ctrl+m to disable the accessibility mode after I launched VS Code.

[image: tab move focus button]

Is there anything I can do to disable this accessibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

#### Pre VS Code 1.83 answer

I suspect you have accidentally touched the `terminal.integrated.tabFocusMode` setting and set it to `true`. Its description reads:

> Controls whether the terminal receives tabs or defers them to the workbench for navigation. When set, this overrides `#editor.tabFocusMode#` when the terminal is focused.

Either that, or you set `editor.tabFocusMode` to `true`, which seems to automatically also change the value of `terminal.integrated.tabFocusMode` to `true` as well unless you manually set it to `false`.

#### VS Code 1.83+ answer

Note that this setting has been removed in VS Code 1.83. See [[Accessibility] Consider removing "terminal.integrated.tabFocusMode" #191938](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191938). Now the way to toggle whether tab moves focus is to use the dedicated mechanism: the `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` command bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.